# Custom Exception when the URL is invalid and when the Database is not connect - Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception, servlets

this example is useful when I want to validate the existence of an object.

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)    
public class CustomGenericException extends RuntimeException {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private String errCode;
        private String errMsg;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/units/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getPages(Integer id)
        throws Exception {

      if ( service.getUnidad(id) == null) {
        // go handleCustomException
        throw new CustomGenericException("E888", "This is custom message");
      }

    }

    @ExceptionHandler(CustomGenericException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleCustomException(CustomGenericException ex) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("error/generic_error");
        model.addObject("errCode", ex.getErrCode());
        model.addObject("errMsg", ex.getErrMsg());

        return model;

    }
```

URL : /units/85
The unit 85 does not exist.

But I want to custime exception when I enter a URL invalid (For example /thisurlnoexists),
and the output should be THIS URL IS INCORRECT.

So I want to know if there is any way to intercept url exepcion customize without having to type throw new EXAMPLEEXCEPTION in the method. The same would like to know if I get an SQL error.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

For 404 page not found , its work fine. The code is

web.xml

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/error</location>
 </error-page>
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping("error")
    public String customError(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("errCode", "324");
        model.addAttribute("errMsg", "PAGE NOT FOUND");    

        return "error";
    }
```

But for Database this code not found

```
  @ControllerAdvice
    public class GeneralExceptionController {

        @ExceptionHandler({SQLException.class,DataAccessException.class})
        public String databaseError(ModelMap model, Exception exception) {
            model.addAttribute("errCode", "ERROR");
            model.addAttribute("errMsg", "SQL");    
            return "error";
        }
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) {


        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("errCode", exception);
        mav.addObject("errMsg", req.getRequestURL());
        mav.setViewName("error");
        return mav;
    }
    }
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sites", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getSites(@RequestParam(required = false) String error, ModelMap modelMap) {  
        List sites = siteBusiness.getAllSites(); //assume that the database is offline, at this point the exception originates
        modelMap.put("sites", sites);        
        return "sites";
    }
```

Comment: Probably you're looking for 404-Page not found error...

Comment: Yes, you're right. How could I do to intercept an error Connection to the database?

Comment: It's weird that your databaseError exception handler cannot see the exception. What is the exception in the logs ?

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Comment: I suppose your GeneralExceptionController is in a package that is scanned through another declaration and it goes in same ApplicationContext as MainController. Did you control it in logs (debug level for org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext) ?

Comment: Yes, for example I add handleError (@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)) and this method catches the exception when the database is off. But databaseError method not.

Comment: Fine, what is the actual exception class according to the `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)` catchall handler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring controller has different notions for inexistant, and invalid Urls.

Taking your example :

- `/uuuunits/*` : `NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException` (at DispatcherServlet level) -> 404
- `/units/foo` : (you asked for an `Integer` ) : `TypeMismatchException` -> 400
- `/units/85` : to be dealt with by controller.

You will find references on Spring Reference Manual/ Web MVC framework / Handling Exceptions

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for Urls that are invalid, it means those URL don't Exist. Hence, all that you need is a 404-Page not Found handler, and you can easily set up that in spring.

About connection error to database, The same applies to it also.

You can make your application container handle such exceptions.

Uncaught exceptions within an application can be forwarded to an error page as defined in the deployment descriptor (web.xml).

```
 <error-page>
     <exception-type>Your-exception-here</exception-type>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

You can a common page for all your DB errors using the following code snippet.

Comment: Its ok with <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/error</location>
    </error-page> but not with <exception-type>java.sql.SQLException</exception-type>